# What's wrong with this TA-Lib function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ta-lib

I'm trying to call TA-lib's ADX function, which according to its documentation, has the following parameters:

```
ADX(high, low, close[, timeperiod=?])

    Average Directional Movement Index (Momentum Indicators)

    Inputs:
        prices: ['high', 'low', 'close']
    Parameters:
        timeperiod: 14
    Outputs:
        real
```

I am calling it like so:

```
from talib import abstract


params = {'timeperiod': 14}

indicator_fn = abstract.Function('ADX')

val = indicator_fn(0.5, 0.2, 0.3, **params)

print(val)
```

But it fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stark/Work/test/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    val = indicator_fn(0.5, 0.2, 0.3, **params)
  File "talib/_abstract.pxi", line 398, in talib._ta_lib.Function.__call__
  File "talib/_abstract.pxi", line 277, in talib._ta_lib.Function.set_function_args
  File "talib/_abstract.pxi", line 462, in talib._ta_lib.Function.__check_opt_input_value
TypeError: Invalid parameter value for timeperiod (expected int, got float)
```

It doesn't seem to make sense to me. `timeperiod` is clearly an `int`, no?

If I attempt to call it like so:

```
val = indicator_fn([0.5, 0.2, 0.3], timeperiod=14)
```

it fails with `TypeError: Invalid parameter value for timeperiod (expected int, got list)`

If I try

```
val = indicator_fn(prices=[0.5, 0.2, 0.3], timeperiod=14)
```

it fails with `KeyError: 0.5`

If I try:

```
val = indicator_fn(prices={'high': 0.5, 'low': 0.2, 'close': 0.3}, timeperiod=14)
```

it fails with `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Any insights here are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3 first args have to be arrays, e.g:

```
val = indicator_fn(np.asarray([0.5]), np.asarray([0.2]), np.asarray([0.3]), timeperiod=14)
```

According to the [tests](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/blob/405f1f6663c516d63add21c69a46f25cdc6ad053/talib/test_abstract.py#L276), `indicator_fn = abstract.Function('ADX', timeperiod=14)` might solve the issue as well.

The error message you're getting is indeed *very* misleading, you might want to report that to the dev.

Answer (score 1):

Oh god, the way to call this ended up being:

```
val = indicator_fn({'high': np.asarray([0.5]), 'low': np.asarray([0.2]), 'close': np.asarray([0.3])}, timeperiod=14)
```

Its working now. /facepalm

Comment: Is `val = indicator_fn(np.asarray([0.5]), np.asarray([0.2]), np.asarray([0.3]), timeperiod=14)` working too?

Comment: Yep, that works as well. Just couldn't figure out what they wanted from the docs and, like you said, the messages were not very helpful.. just tried combinations until something worked.

Comment: OK. Then the issue was the 3 first args have to be arrays, as in the tests I linked. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved mine as well for `LINEARREG_ANGLE` with the following snippet:

```
ANGLE = abstract.Function('LINEARREG_ANGLE')
slope = ANGLE({'close': np.asarray(ema), 'timeperiod': slope_period})
```